# How to programmatically change the CDF files for some files in oracle UCM site?

Tags: oracle, web-services, oracle-ucm

I have around 20 files for which I want to replace the CDF files. The files are in different directory structure. For example:

Site/dir1/page1
Site/dir2/page3
Site/dir3/page1

I would like to checkin 3 new CDF files and assign to each of the above files.

Comment: To confirm, you have CDFs and want to check them in and then assign them to certain sections? If so, is there a reason you cannot do it manually (other that it being time consuming)?

Comment: Yes you are right, I have CDF'S. This is an example- there are 2600 files to be added/modified. The backup plan is to do it manually. But wanted to see if there is any east script or solution to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [RIDC code](https://jonathanhult.com/blog/2012/12/ridc-examples/) to call the [CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e11011/c05_core003.htm#CSSRG2201) to checkin the files. You could then call the appropriate [Site Studio service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e10615/c11_ss_services.htm#SSTRF408) to assign the CDF to the proper section. You would need logic for programatically determining this.

Also, please see this note: https://jonathanhult.com/blog/2014/11/statement-direction-site-studio/

Comment: I need help in oeacle UCM. Do you know if there is a way to clone the Site created in Oracle UCM?